# Seeking open SNMP data

Tags: snmp

I want to code an SNMP decoder, but only have simplistic examples.

I would strongly prefer SNMP Get Responses - as raw hex dumps. I would like to see a response for a Get with multiple OIDs; even better if the response values are of different data types (int, string, bool, etc).

I would settle for details of the parameters to an SMP Get command which will return me a raw hex dump. Failing that just the command line and I can capture the raw hex with Wireshark.